# Retrieve checkbox input in display tag by using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, displaytag

I have used the display tag library to display my first returned results in JSP file. For further processing purpose, I need the selected checkbox values and manipulate them in the Javascript. However, I couldn't get them by using getElementsByName() function. Hope someone here can kindly give me some suggestions to proceed. Thanks a lot!

Following are my display table code in JSP file:

```
<display:table name="${List}" id="row" class="displaytable">
    <display:column title="Equipment" class="fieldAlignCenter">
          <c:forEach var="deviceRow" items="${row.getDeviceList()}">
              <input type="checkbox" name="equipNo" value="${deviceRow.equipNo}">
              <c:out value="${deviceRow.equipNo}" />
          </c:forEach>
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you also assign an ID to the checkbox.
This id can be the same as name.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="equipNo" id="equipNo" value="${deviceRow.equipNo}">
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(document.getElementById('equipNo').checked);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, I have added the ID to the checkbox while it still showed me the  result is "undefined". Is there any declaration I miss there in Javascript?

Comment: an checkbox doesn't have a value. It is checked or not checked.
`<input type="checkbox" checked>` and in javascript: `document.getElementById('checkboxid').checked` this will be true if it's checked, false if it's unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Add id to input tag like this

```
<display:table name="${List}" id="row" class="displaytable">
    <display:column title="Equipment" class="fieldAlignCenter">
          <c:forEach var="deviceRow" items="${row.getDeviceList()}">
              <input type="checkbox" id="equipNo_id" name="equipNo" value="${deviceRow.equipNo}">
              <c:out value="${deviceRow.equipNo}" />
          </c:forEach>
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```

and use `document.getElementById("equipNo_id").checked`

Comment: Dear Toms, Thanks for your suggestions. While I have tested the result by changed the code same with your example. However, it still show me the alert "undefined" which is the same result with getElementsByName() function.

Comment: Another concern is getElementById() function only provides the result of first element with specific id based on the documentation http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp